# alljoyn Application build error #error No OS GROUP DEFINED

Tags: build, makefile, openwrt, alljoyn

I am trying to build one alljoyn application for openwrt.
I am getting the following error

```
usr/include/qcc/platform.h:32:2 error: #error No OS GROUP defined.
```

I am using Makefile to build my application. 
I have two makefiles. 
My top level Makefile's compile section looks like

```
define Build/Compile
$(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
C_INCLUDE_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include" \
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include" \
CC="$(TARGET_CC)" \
WS=off \
EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS) -DQCC_OS_GROUP_POSIX -DQCC_OS_LINUX"  \
CROSS_COMPILE="$(TARGET_CROSS)" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include \
 -I$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include/uClibc++ -fno-builtin -fno-rtti \
 -nostdinc++ -fpermissive -Wno-error"  \
LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS) -lalljoyn -lcrypt -ldl $(GpioLdflags-y)"
endef
```

and the makefile inside src directory looks like as follows.

```
CC     := $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
all : aj-sample
%.o : %.cc
    $(CC) -c $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $<

LIBS := -lalljoyn -luClibc++ -lpthread 

aj-sample : aj-sample.o
     $(LD) aj-sample.o $(LIBS) $<

clean : 
    -rm -f *.o
```

I also tried adding -DQCC_OS_GROUP_POSIX -DQCC_OS_LINUX in src level makefile. But the issue still remains same.

I have already installed the alljoyn from openwrt feeds which compiles successfully. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm asking just for curiosity, why don't you use the scons build system that is bundled with the AllJoyn

Comment: I have the same problem. Probably because he would like to implement the SDK into his own custom application e.g. inside Eclipse project. Is this possible to do with scons also in this way?